# Why am I getting an index error after reading in data and splitting the data into a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, indexing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michael.ramage\Desktop\Carbon.py", line 12, in <module>
    carbon_i = float(X[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am reading in data from a notepad file to use for matlab. The data I have is for carbon (in ppm). Every year, an average for carbon is taken everyday, then the average for the month is taken. 12 times per year this information is reported. For example, in 1960, each month has its own measurement. I only want the first column (year) and the 4th column (carbon dioxide in ppm) - **index 0 and 3.** This text file is very long. It goes up to 2017 to month 9. If I can attach a file, I will.

```
1960   1    1960.042      316.43      316.43      316.51     -1
1960   2    1960.125      316.97      316.97      316.47     -1
1960   3    1960.208      317.58      317.58      316.49     -1
1960   4    1960.292      319.02      319.02      316.86     -1
1960   5    1960.375      320.03      320.03      317.24     -1
1960   6    1960.458      319.59      319.59      317.36     -1
1960   7    1960.542      318.18      318.18      317.30     -1
1960   8    1960.625      315.91      315.91      316.92     -1
1960   9    1960.708      314.16      314.16      316.87     -1
1960  10    1960.792      313.83      313.83      316.76     -1
1960  11    1960.875      315.00      315.00      316.98     -1
1960  12    1960.958      316.19      316.19      317.13     -1

info = {}
s=" "
with open("data.txt") as inData:
    while s != "":
        average = 0
        for line in range(12):
            s = inData.readline()
            x = s.rstrip("\n").split() 
            carbon_i = float(x[3]) #the error occurs here
            average += carbon_i
            if line == 12:
                info[x[0]] = average
            else:
                pass

print("done")
```

In the code above, I am reading a line (and removing \n) and then I strip it to create a list so that I can use its index. I want average, for each month per year, the carbon dioxide in ppm. For example, I would take index 3 of the provided data and average those. After, I put the year (key) and average (value) in a dictionary. The year will be the key and the average of the carbon for 12 months will be the value.

Comment: an empty line somewhere could explain that. Check if you have enough item before using `[]`

Comment: you are getting an error because there is a line in the file that does not have 3 items on it. use a `try:` `except IndexError:` block to investigate which line it is.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The file the same amount of elements for every line until the end of document. There are also no empty spots (blank lines) unless python reads the line after the last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the body of the `while` loop will continue executing when you encounter a blank line. Here is an adjustment that will fix this:

```
info = {}
s=" "
with open("data.txt") as inData:
    while True:
        average = 0
        for line in range(12):
            s = inData.readline() # this could be a blank line
            x = s.rstrip("\n").split() # if s is blank, x is an empty list
            try:
                carbon_i = float(x[3]) # if x is empty, this will cause an error
            except IndexError:
                break # handle the error by exiting the while loop
            average += carbon_i
            if line == 12:
                info[x[0]] = average
            else:
                pass

print("done")
```

Worth noting: this loop will not end if there aren't any blank lines in the file.

Comment: I would suggest doing away with the while loop altogether, to be honest. I'll edit to illustrate..

Comment: Apologies, I'll have to do it later if I have time.